la consola de output de netbeans no muestra el caracter ñ
la consola de salida de netbeans no muestra los caracter ñ. Muestra un simbolo raro en su lugar. Al hacer un System.out.println("Niño"); esto es lo que muestra: Ni�o

Tienes que editar netbeans.conf en tu instalación, como lo indican en este post: https://joseblanco.pro/utf-8-netbeans/
